# ROS: Transformer is always empty

Tags: python, ros

Theoretically, the `tf.Transformer` should return a list of frames from the `/tf` node using the `getFrameStrings()` module, but the list it returns is always empty.

The tidbit code in which I use it is below:

```
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    t = tf.Transformer(True, rospy.Duration(10.0))
    rospy.loginfo("list: %s", t.getFrameStrings())
```

Every log just says list: []

If I echo `tf` it shows about 30 different frames at the time.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the tf.TransformListener class should be used to access the frames from the tf topic in python. It is "a subclass of tf.TransformerROS that subscribes to the "/tf" message topic", and tf.TransformerROS extends tf.Transformer ([see docs](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf/html/python/tf_python.html#transformlistener)).

Also, I would initialize the TransformListener before the loop to give it some time to collect the transforms. So with your code piece like this:

```
t = tf.TransformListener(True, rospy.Duration(10.0))
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    rospy.loginfo("list: %s", t.getFrameStrings())
```

it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The Transformer object requires a data source. The TransformListener object will subscribe to the tf topic and call Transformer.setTransform when new data arrives so as to be able to be queried.

There's a tutorial here: http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28Python%29

Also I suggest searching http://answers.ros.org for similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

An example from http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf/html/python/tf_python.html

```
t = tf.Transformer(True, rospy.Duration(10.0))
t.getFrameStrings() # prints []
m = geometry_msgs.msg.TransformStamped()
m.header.frame_id = 'THISFRAME'
m.child_frame_id = 'CHILD'
m.transform.translation.x = 2.71828183
m.transform.rotation.w = 1.0
t.setTransform(m)
t.getFrameStrings() # prints ['/CHILD', '/THISFRAME']
```